# Variables in different breeds

Tags: netlogo

i'm trying to make an archaeological model, in which hunters are making paintings in shelters, depending on their quality.

```
breed [shelters shelter]
breed [hunters hunter]
shelters-own [quality paintings]
```

The value of each shelter quality is set in the setup (with a slider for the actual number of shelters).

```
create-shelters number-shelters [set quality random 100]
```

The action of painting-or-not is then defined by random against the quality of each shelter:

```
to make-painting
  ask shelters [
    if any? hunters-on patch-here [
        if random 100 < quality [set paintings paintings + 1]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Now, I would like to complexify it a bit more: the quality wouldn't be defined by the shelter itself (and thus be the same for every hunter), but by the hunters: each of them would attribute a different quality for each shelter. The action of painting-or-not would still be a test against random, but with this new variable defined by each individual hunter...

But I can't find a way to code it down properly.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Do hunters move to different shelters?  Do you want the a given hunter to always assign the same quality to a given shelter?  If you want the evaluation to persist then, if it has any random component, you will need to store it.  (Unfortunately, tables cannot use patches as keys, but you can key on the patch location as a list of integers.)

Comment: Hunters move randomly and visit different shelters (I made the model to stop when one shelter gets 100 paintings). Indeed, the idea is that, if there are, for an example, 10 shelters, every hunter would have a different variable of 10 quality values, persistent from setup. How do you store and retrieve these values from patches?

Comment: Then why not give each hunter a `shelters` attribute that is a list of length 10 (or however many shelters  you have) and stores the quality of each shelter in the list.  To make the accounting easier, you could assign each shelter a shelter index (e.g., 0 through 9) and use this to index the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it right. Basically, I had every hunter to create a matrix filled with random numbers. The size is 33x33, so it goes all over the world (had to set it to start in a corner, or it gets negative coordinates).

```
create-hunters number-hunters [
  set color white 
  set size 1
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  set hunter-matrix matrix:make-constant 33 33 random 10
]
ask n-of number-shelters patches [
  sprout-shelters 1 [ 
    set color one-of base-colors 
    set size 1 
    set xpatch xcor set ypatch ycor
]
```

Then, when they would reach a shelter, the value corresponding to that patch location would be extracted and used to paint-or-not.

```
ask patches [
  ask hunters-here [set quality matrix:get hunter-matrix xpatch ypatch]
  let paintings-here sum [paintings] of shelters-here
  if any? hunters-here and any? shelters-here [
    if random 10 < quality [
      ask shelters-here [
        set paintings paintings + 1]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I'm still not completely sure it actually does what I think it's doing, tho.